# Splatting a function with an object's property

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, splat

In PowerShell you can pass multiple parameters to a function or cmdlet by wrapping them in a hashtable variable, then passing that variable prefixed with `@` instead of `$`.

Is it possible to splat with a hashtable which is a property of another object (i.e. as a one liner)?  e.g. below I first have to assign the property (`testInt`, `testString`) to another variable before I can splat it to `Demo`.  I'd like some way to avoid this additional step, but haven't been able to find a neat solution...

```
function Demo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$One
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Two
    )
    "1 = $One"
    "2 = $Two"
}
$test = @{
    testInt = @{ 
        One = '1'
        Two = '2'
    }
    testString = @{
        One = 'One'
        Two = 'Two'
    }
}

$t = $test.testInt
Demo @t 
$t = $test.testString
Demo @t

Demo @test.testInt #this doesn't work / I've also tried similar options with various castings and braces though to no avail.
```

---

**Update**

Suggestion submitted: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5227

Comment: Did you try `@($test.testInt)`?

Comment: @Clijsters: Yes; but sadly no joy.

Comment: @Clijsters `@()` is the array construction operator. Even if you wrap that around a parameter it won't enable splatting functionality.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: my bad. I tried a similiar thing and it worked for me, as a one-element Array is represented as it's only item. It doesn't work with the OP's example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to splat an object property or an element of an array or hashtable is to assign it to a variable and then splat that variable

```
$p = $variable.property
demo @p
```

The notation `@variable.property` is invalid, and neither `@()` nor `@{}` could be used to allow such syntax, since they already have different meanings (array construction and hashtable construction).

Comment: FYI: Have submitted this as a suggestion: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5227... Hopefully this will be useful to others / accepted.