# How can I splat a hashtable directly from a class static method?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, static-methods

How can I get the same output as:

```
$ht = @{Object="Hi there";Foregroundcolor="Green"}
Write-Host @ht
```

without using a/the variable `$ht` ?

Don't get me wrong, I know how to use a basic CMDLet.
I have a static method that generates dynamic hashtables.
Look at this simplified example code:

```
class HashtableGenerator
{
    static [hashtable]Answer()
    {
        return @{Object="Hallo Welt";ForegroundColor="Green"}
    }
}
$ht = [HashtableGenerator]::Answer()
Write-Host @ht
```

This works just fine, but is it possible to get rid of the `$ht` variable, so the code would look *something* like this:

```
Write-Host @([HashtableGenerator]::Answer()) # Doesn't work
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly like you want since you can only splat variables.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927822/splatting-a-function-with-an-objects-property

Comment: As an aside: There is an [RFC suggesting implementation of what you're looking for](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Language-RFC/blob/master/1-Draft/RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting.md) in a future PowerShell (Core) version: expression-based [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) that doesn't require an intermediate variable. The discussion associated with the RFC is [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking to do is not possible at least at this time. Splatting is specific to hashtable and array *variables* explicitly. Not return values of functions, methods etc. [Technet for splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) sort of supports this

> Splatting is a method of passing a collection of parameter values to a command as unit. PowerShell associates each value in the collection with a command parameter. **Splatted parameter values are stored in named splatting variables**, which look like standard variables, but begin with an At symbol (@) instead of a dollar sign ($). The At symbol tells PowerShell that you are passing a collection of values, instead of a single value.

Using the @ outside of that will tell PowerShell to treat the results as an array. IIRC there is a semi related feature request to splat directly from a hashtable definition instead of saving to a variable first.

---

Related question talking about splatting from a variable property: [Splatting a function with an object's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927822/splatting-a-function-with-an-objects-property)

Comment: Note that splatting also works with _array_ variables. The RFC for allowing expression-based splatting is [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Language-RFC/blob/master/1-Draft/RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting.md) and the associated discussion [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/6).

Answer (score -2):

Passing function parameters using hashtable is just the same way you implicitly specify them. Hashtable key works as parameter name and its corresponding hashtable value uses as parameter value.

```
Write-Host -Object 'Hi there' -Foregroundcolor 'Green'
```

Comment: The question was how to use hashtable-based [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) without requiring an _intermediate variable_ - specifying arguments individually doesn't help.